# CheckInGatedChanges Activity Location In Build Workflow

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, tfsbuild

The default build template has the `CheckInGatedChanges` activity ("Check In Gated Changes") being ran outside of the `AgentScope` activity ("Run on Agent").

Is there a reason for this?  Or rather, could the `CheckInGatedChanges` activity be moved into the end of the `AgentScope` flow (end of sequence)?

My *guess* is that Microsoft does not want the agent itself to check-in the changes, but the controller.  I am not sure though as I do not know the inner workings of the controller-agent model they have.

The reason I ask is because I **need** to have an activity run ***after*** the changes are checked-in, and that is currently forcing me to use another instance of the AgentScope activity.  I would prefer to just put them all in the first AgentScope activity and not use extra resources.

Answer (score 3):

The current location of CheckInGatedChanges in the template makes sure that if you add extra activities to the template, they are not unexpectedly run after the changes have been committed to the server. Furthermore, it allows parallel agent execution to happen. For example, if you want to parallelize the build to multiple agents for scaling, the checkin would need to occur after all the build agent workflows finish.

Those are the reasons I can think of. I think it is safe, if you know that you don't need a convergent point for checking in your changes, to move the CheckInGatedChanges activity into the AgentScope so that you don't have to spawn another AgentScope to do your custom work. I don't think we restrict the scope of this activity.

Comment: So from what you say, it seems to be aesthetic.  In other words, so developers in general remember to not put activities underneath it.  Is that basically what you were saying?

Comment: That and to support parallel build if desired.

Comment: I tried this out, and it actually does not work. Not 100% at least. On manual builds, sure.  But with a gated check-in, it fails the build with this error: TF270012: There is no shelveset available to check in.

Comment: Probably at that point the build information data that contains the shelveset to check in has not been saved to the server. You've just found that it's not possible to use this CheckInGatedChanges activity in the AgentScope for TFS 2010. Going with this activity on the controller is what you have for now. On the other note, can you share why you need to run AgentScope again (what custom tasks you want to do that require AgentScope)?

Comment: I am packaging my output into a zip/self extracting EXE file using a combination of activities.  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.DownloadFiles, and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CopyDirectory are the key ones. Most importantly, the input parameter on the activity DownloadFiles that I use is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec.Latest.DisplayString.  So I am using the latest version from source control.  This makes my package behind the build because it isn't checked in yet.  So I have to change the order of activities.